# Why is my computed property not effective after Object.assign?

Tags: javascript, computed-properties

I stumbled upon code similar to this in modern JavaScript:

```js
let obj = {
  data: {number: 9},
  set prop(p) {
    this.data = p;
  },
  get prop() {
    return this.data;
  }
};

obj = Object.assign({}, obj, {
  data: {number: 2}
});

console.log('obj.data === obj.prop ', obj.data === obj.prop);
console.log('obj.data.number === obj.prop.number ', obj.data.number === obj.prop.number);
```

Any modification is done outside of the computed property, as if there were none.

I was expecting the computed property to still exist.

Is there a way to preserve the computed property after a call to `Object.assign`? Thanks.

Comment: The whole point of object assign is you are creating a new object, and not a reference to the original. What is your expected output in this example?

Comment: I would expect the property (the actual get and set) to be assign to the new object, calling the property on the new one and getting/setting though the new obj.data. I mean, conceptually they are both the same object type?

Comment: They are the same object "type" but you are using ===, no two objects will be evaluate to equal here, even if their contents are the same, unless one is referencing the original

Comment: From your code: obj.data = {number: 2}, obj.prop = {number: 9}, thus obj.data != obj.prop

Comment: @Iracicot Even if number was 9 in both of them, they would still evaluate to false

Comment: @adiga I went ahead and flagged this for you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the result of the new object created by `object.assign` you will see that it no longer has getter/setter, but has a property `prop`. `object.assign` doesn't copy the getter/setter functions over but instead calls `[[get]]` and makes a new property.

[MDN describes it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

> It uses [[Get]] on the source and [[Set]] on the target, so it will invoke getters and setters. Therefore it assigns properties versus just copying or defining new properties. This may make it unsuitable for merging new properties into a prototype if the merge sources contain getters.

So `assign()` merges an object with a `prop` property together with an object with a `data` property and you get both:

```js
let obj = {
  data: {
    number: 9
  },

  set prop(p) {
    this.data = p;
  },

  get prop() {
    return this.data;
  }

};

obj = Object.assign({}, obj, {
  data: {
    number: 2
  }
});

// it has a data and a prop property -- they are not the same:
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Good thanks. But then I still have to find a way to keep the property, oh well...

Comment: [Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40211763/3082296)  which uses `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()` to demonstrate this.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot, I'm not sure how you're using this, but you might be able to get the behavior you want by creating a new object with `let newObj = Object.create(obj)` and then setting the `data` property on the new object. It will inherit the getter/setter from the parent.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I want `obj.oldData` to always yield `obj.wrapper.oldData`. I want incremental migration of a feature.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the following:

```js
let ex = {
  o: 1
}

let ex2 = {
  o: 1
}

console.log(ex === ex2);
```

Identical objects to not equate.

Comment: I know that, but how does `obj.data` and `obj.prop` don't yield the exact same object?