# Object.assign alternative for getters/setters

Tags: javascript

`Object.assign()` does not work with getters and setters (because it only reads the property *values*, as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40211725/object-assign-getters-and-setters-in-constructor)):

```js
> let a = {}
> Object.defineProperty(a, "foo", {get: () => "bar"})
> a.foo
'bar'
> let b = Object.assign({}, a)
> b.foo
undefined
```

What are my alternatives to `Object.assign` here, if I want to include `foo` in `b`?

Comment: _"The `Object.assign()` method only copies enumerable and own properties from a source object to a target object. It uses `[[Get]]` on the source and `[[Set]]` on the target, so it will invoke getters and setters. **Therefore it assigns properties, versus copying or defining new properties. This may make it unsuitable for merging new properties into a prototype if the merge sources contain getters**."_ (Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign))

Comment: @HarunYilmaz Thank you! That explains why, but doesn't tell me what to do instead.

Comment: This might also help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34480936/cloning-a-javascript-object-including-getters-and-setters

Comment: @leo On what you asked, if i'd work if you add a setter. Added a working code. But also note that you'll explicitly have to set `enumerable: true` otherwise it'll not copy since `Object.defineProperty` sets it to false by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `Object.create` and use prototypal inheritance:

```js
let a = {};
Object.defineProperty(a, "foo", { get: () => "foo" });
console.log(a.foo);
let b = Object.create(a);
console.log(b.foo);
```

But then mutations `a` (if it can have other properties besides `foo`) will be automatically reflected in `b`, I don't know whether that's the desired behavior. Maybe doing

```
let b = Object.create(a);
Object.assign(b, a);
```

will solve both problems.

Answer (score 2):

You need to capture setters and getter directly, because

> The `Object.assign()` method only copies enumerable and own properties from a source object to a target object. It uses `[[Get]]` on the source and `[[Set]]` on the target, so it will invoke [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set). Therefore it assigns properties, versus copying or defining new properties. This may make it unsuitable for merging new properties into a prototype if the merge sources contain getters.
>
> **For copying property definitions (including their enumerability) into prototypes, use [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor) and [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) instead.** [[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Description); emp: ns]

and take some code from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Copying_accessors).

```js
// This is an assign function that copies full descriptors
function completeAssign(target, ...sources) {
  sources.forEach(source => {
    let descriptors = Object.keys(source).reduce((descriptors, key) => {
      descriptors[key] = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(source, key);
      return descriptors;
    }, {});

    // By default, Object.assign copies enumerable Symbols, too
    Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(source).forEach(sym => {
      let descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(source, sym);
      if (descriptor.enumerable) {
        descriptors[sym] = descriptor;
      }
    });
    Object.defineProperties(target, descriptors);
  });
  return target;
}

const obj = {
  foo: 1,
  get bar() {
    return 2;
  }
};

let copy = Object.assign({}, obj);
console.log(copy);
// { foo: 1, bar: 2 }
// The value of copy.bar is obj.bar's getter's return value.


copy = completeAssign({}, obj);
console.log(copy);
// { foo:1, get bar() { return 2 } }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

> The Object.assign() method only copies enumerable and own properties from a source object to a target object. It uses [[Get]] on the source and [[Set]] on the target, so it will invoke getters and setters.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Since you have only set `getter` for `foo` and not have any `setter` it'll not be copied.

Checked out the bellow example, you might find it interesting.

```js
a = {};

Object.defineProperty(a, "foo", {get: () => "bar"});

console.log(a.foo);

a.foo = 1

console.log(a.foo); // logs bar and not 1
```

**Solution**

Add a setter too!

```js
var a = {};

(function(){
  var fooValue = 'bar';

  Object.defineProperty(a, "foo", {
    get: () => {return fooValue},
    set: (newFoo)=>{fooValue = newFoo},
    enumerable: true // Defaults to 'false', which will not copy the property
  });
})();

var b = Object.assign({}, a);

console.log(a, b);
```

**Note**: This will copy the property as is without the setter or getter method. If you have some custom logic in `setter` or `getter` it'd not work in the copy.